# Array Bidimensional

Tags: javascript, dom

Gostaria de percorrer com for um array bidimensional conforme o código:

```
var cadeiras = [[true, false, true, true, true, false, false, true, true, true, false, false], 
               [true, false, true, true, true, false, false, true, true, true, false, false], 
               [true, false, true, true, true, false, false, true, true, true, false, false], 
               [true, false, true, true, true, false, false, true, true, true, false, false]];

for (i = 0, i < cadeiras.length, i++){
for (j = 0, j < cadeiras[i].length; j++) {
    if([i][j]){
    var reserva = confirm("A cadeira " + (j+1) + " na fila " + (i+1) + " está disponível. Deseja reservá-la?");
        if(reserva){
            document.getElementById("assento" + numeroCadeira).src = "img/cadeira-tulipa-reservada.jpg"
            document.getElementById("assento" + numeroCadeira).alt = "reservada"
            document.getElementById(numeroCadeira).classList.remove("panel-default");
            document.getElementById(numeroCadeira).classList.add("panel-success");
            alert("A cadeira " + (j+1) + " na fila " + (i+1) + " está reservada.");
            break;
        }
    }   
}
```

}

O objetivo é verificar se a cadeira está livre e caso esteja livre dar ao usuário a opção de aceitá-la.
Caso seja aceita, o loop deve ser interrompido.

Desde já agradeço a ajuda.

Comment: E qual o problema? Aparentemente o código já esta fazendo esse trabalho.

Comment: O código, como estava, não estava rodando por conta dos problemas de ponto e vírgula e do break que não estava sendo usado de forma correta.  

Obrigado pelo seu comentário.

Comment: Não tinha reparado. De nada, precisando só chamar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Situação

Pelo que notei esta é uma rotina que você ira chamar varias vezes, ou seja se deve atualizar o valor das cadeiras.

#### Problemas

- Como ja apontados pelas demais respostas, você esta usando `,` no lugar de `;` nas divições do `for`.
- Sua verificação esta `if([i][j])`, não sei qual array ele esta comparando aqui, diria um dado aleatório.
- você nao esta ajustando o valor da cadeira.
- Para sair de uma iteração em javascript se usa `return` não `break`.

#### [Codigo](http://jsfiddle.net/ncttqL3r/)

```
var cadeiras = [
    [true, false, true, true, true, false, false, true, true, true, false, false],
    [true, false, true, true, true, false, false, true, true, true, false, false], 
    [true, false, true, true, true, false, false, true, true, true, false, false], 
    [true, false, true, true, true, false, false, true, true, true, false, false]
];

function reservar(){
    for (i = 0; i < cadeiras.length; i++){
        for (j = 0; j < cadeiras[i].length; j++) {
            if(cadeiras[i][j]){
                if(confirm("A cadeira " + (j+1) + " na fila " + (i+1) + " está disponível. Deseja reservá-la?")){
                    console.log("A cadeira " + (j+1) + " na fila " + (i+1) + " foi reservada");
                    cadeiras[i][j] = false;
                    return;
                }
            }   
        }
    }
}
reservar();
reservar();
```

#### OBS

Eu faria em uma função encapsulada, para não usar variável global.

Comment: Ótimo Guilherme. 
Muito obrigado pela resposta.
Na verdade esse é só um trecho de um código maior.
Tudo está em um IIFE. Mas mesmo assim obrigado pela dica.

Answer (score 3):

Primeiramente, corrija a sintaxe do `for` substituindo `,` por `;`

Depois, para sair de ambos os loops ao mesmo tempo, o `break` não resolverá. Encapsule tudo dentro de uma **function**, e ao reservar a cadeira, chame `return` para sair de ambos os loops.

```
function reservarCadeiraDisponivel() {
    for (i = 0; i < cadeiras.length; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < cadeiras[i].length; j++) {
            if ([i][j]) {
                var reserva = confirm("A cadeira " + (j + 1) + " na fila " + (i + 1) + " está disponível. Deseja reservá-la?");
                if (reserva) {
                    document.getElementById("assento" + numeroCadeira).src = "img/cadeira-tulipa-reservada.jpg"
                    document.getElementById("assento" + numeroCadeira).alt = "reservada"
                    document.getElementById(numeroCadeira).classList.remove("panel-default");
                    document.getElementById(numeroCadeira).classList.add("panel-success");
                    alert("A cadeira " + (j + 1) + " na fila " + (i + 1) + " está reservada.");
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }

  alert("Nenhuma cadeira disponível");
  return;
}
```

Comment: Obrigado alvarodms.
O problema era exatamente esse.

Answer (score 2):

A syntax do seu `for` esta errada, se usa `;` e não `,`, fiz um exemplo que retornará todos os valores, dentro do if basta colocar a ação se a cadeira estiver vaga:

```js
var cadeiras = [
  [true, false, true],
  [false, false],
  [true]
];

for (i = 0; i < cadeiras.length; i++) {
  for (j = 0; j < cadeiras[i].length; j++) {
    console.log(cadeiras[i][j]);
    if (cadeiras[i][j]) {
      var reserva = confirm("A cadeira " + (j + 1) + " na fila " + (i + 1) + " está disponível. Deseja reservá-la?");
      if (reserva) {
        // faça algo se for reservado.
        return false; // saia do loop.
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Veja funcionando no: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vqhftwgx/)

Comment: Perfeito Gabriel.
Muito obrigado pela resposta.

Answer (score 1):

Me parece algo muito simples, segue um exemplo:

Considere que uma matriz percorre os elementos através de um axis:

```
+------------------> x
|[true, false, ...]
|[true, false, ...]
|[true, false, ...] 
v
y
```

Para percorrer em javascript, basta fazer algo assim, e armazenar os dados em um objeto.

```
 var cadeiras = [
                 [true, false, true, true, true, false, false, true, true, true, false, false], 
                 [true, false, true, true, true, false, false, true, true, true, false, false], 
                 [true, false, true, true, true, false, false, true, true, true, false, false], 
                 [true, false, true, true, true, false, false, true, true, true, false, false]
                ];
     var free = {"acesso":false};
    for (var y in cadeiras) {
          var x = 0;
          //percorre enquanto for indisponível
          while (cadeiras[y][x] === false) {
            x++; 
          } 
           //sai quando achar o disponível
           free = {"acesso":cadeiras[y][x], "x":x, "y": y}; 
          break;
    }
console.log(free); //a saída será: {acesso: true, x: 0, y: "0"}
```

Depois é só exibir o objeto:

```
alert("A cadeira "+free.x+" da fila "+free.y+" está "+((free.acesso) ? 'livre' : 'indisponível')+"!");
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta Ivan.